# Installing docker on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, docker

The installation instructions go up to Xenial... https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/ . Any idea how to install it on Yakkety?

Comment: Just used Xenial sources...seems to be working at first glance.

Comment: ```curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Xenial sources, they should work fine. Yakkety won't be up until Docker 1.13.

Answer (score 15):

I have managed to run docker on Ubuntu 16.10 as follows:

1.Update apt and install required certificates

    `$ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates`

2. Add the GPG key to apt

    `$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D`

3. Add the docker repo to the apt list

    `echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`

4. Update apt

    `sudo apt-get update`

5. Check that the repo contains the docker installers

```
  $ apt-cache policy docker-engine

  docker-engine:
    Installed: 1.12.2-0~trusty
    Candidate: 1.12.2-0~trusty
    Version table:
   *** 1.12.2-0~trusty 0
          500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
       1.12.1-0~trusty 0
          500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
       1.12.0-0~trusty 0
          500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

6. Install the docker engine

`$ sudo apt-get install docker-engine`

7.Start the docker daemon.

`$ sudo service docker start`

8. Verify that docker is installed correctly by running the hello-world image.

`$ sudo docker run hello-world`

Comment: This works for 16.04 and 16.10, the new docker-ce has errors with a daemon.json file.

Comment: For 16.10 docker has a testing repo 'deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-yakkety main testing', got it from here http://www.openfoam.com/download/install-binary-linux.php

Answer (score 6):

Just run : `sudo apt-get install docker.io` and you're good to go.

Comment: This literally saved my day

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to install docker on Ubuntu using following command that you can get from the https://get.docker.com/

This script is meant for quick & easy install via:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

or

```
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

For test builds (ie. release candidates):

```
$ curl -fsSL https://test.docker.com | sh
```

or

```
 wget -qO- https://test.docker.com/ | sh
```

For rc build with experimental feature:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://experimental.docker.com | sh
```

or

```
 wget -qO- https://experimental.docker.com/ | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I have installed docker in ubuntu 16.04 with following spates. Please use the following commands.

```
$ sudo su
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
$ add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install docker-ce
$ usermod -aG docker {non root user}
$ systemctl restart docker
$ systemctl enable docker
```

Also check this URL for more info [enter link description here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04)
after that we need to test the docker is running or not. For that the command is

```
$ systemctl is-active docker
```

Check container running

```
$ docker container ls -a
```

Now we need to pull image from Docker Hub and install into container

```
$ docker pull ubuntu
```

To rename image name find the following command

```
$ docker tag Old_Image_Name New_Image_Name
```

Now we have to run this image into a container. Where container 80 port will map with host 8000 port

```
$ docker run -h hostname -p 8000:80 --name Mycontainer -it ubuntu bash
```

If you want to come out from container to your previous use then press the following key

```
Ctrl + P + Q
```

And if you want to again get into container

```
$ docker exec -it {container id} /bin/bash
```

Now if you want to copy your project into container

```
$ docker cp src/. mycontainer:/target
$ docker cp mycontainer:/src/. target
```

Suppose, if you want to delete the image then the command will be

```
$ docker rmi {image name}
```

But if that image tag with a running container. then we have to stop the container first.

```
$ docker stop {container name}
```

Install docker compose

```
$ sudo apt install docker-compose
```

Creation Image from docker container

```
$ docker commit {container ID} {docker hub username/image name : tag}
```

Login to docker hubs

```
$ docker login
```

to push local image in to your personal repo.

```
$ docker push {image mane}
```

Answer (score 0):

#Update the apt package index and install packages

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install 
ca-certificates 
curl 
gnupg 
lsb-release

#Add Docker's official GPG key:
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg

#Use the following command to set up the stable repository.
echo 
"deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu 
$(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

#Install Docker Engine
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io